# How to pass variable(list of data) from python to template and display with using jinja for loop

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I'm pretty new to python and learning how to pass list from python to template. 
So from the code below,
'result' is the list of hashtags that I extract from the caption data.

What I'm trying to do is pass this list to template and use jinja for loop to display in html file.(Mainly I'm not really sure if my displayHashtag() function is correct)

```
import requests
import re
from flask import Flask, 
render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

TARGETURL = "https://www.instagram.com/"
USERNAME = "username"

r = requests.get( TARGETURL + USERNAME + "/")

def getCaption(text):
    captions = 
re.findall(r"edge_media_to_caption\":{\"edges\":\[{\"node\":{\"text\":\"(.+?)\"}",text)
    return captions

def getHashtags(text):
    hashtags = re.findall(r"#([a-zA-Z]+)", text)
    return hashtags

printCaption = getCaption(r.text)
printHashtags = 
getHashtags(printCaption[0])

result = []
for caption in printCaption :
    result += getHashtags(caption)
print("Show me all the hashtags : ")
print(result)

@app.route('/')
def displayHashtag():
    return render_template('HashtagList.html', result = result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True)
```

HashtagList file ----

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
{% for hashtag in result %}
    <li>{{ hashtag }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please include the file `HashtagList.html` in your question, or at least the relevant part of it?

Comment: I just added at the end of the post!

Comment: works for me. did you put the `HashtagList.html` in a `/templates` directory in the root of your `app`?

Comment: Yeah this looks fine. What is the actual problem you are having? Is Flask outputting any errors to the console when you run your application?

Comment: It works now! I put the html file in wrong directory!